# woocommerce custom registration template validation error message not under each field

Tags: woocommerce, registration

Please guide me to add validation error message under each field on WooCommerce custom registration page template.

So *i* have created Registration page template and put all code from `woocommerce/myaccount/form-login.php`.

I added custom validation rules using the code below:

```php
function custom_woocommerce_process_registration_errors( $validation_errors, $username, $password, $email ){

    if ( !isset( $_POST['billing_first_name'] ) || $_POST['billing_first_name'] == '' ) {
        $validation_errors->add( 'billing_first_name', __( 'Please enter First Name!!!!!!.', 'woocommerce' ) );
    }
    
    return $validation_errors;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_process_registration_errors', 'custom_woocommerce_process_registration_errors', 10, 4 );
```

Now, How can I display this error message under each field. Currently, all errors are displaying at the top of the page like in bunch. I want to display each message under the respective field. I do much R&D but nothing found.

I try some of action and filter hook but thats not working as per my requirment.